# Reading an xml file without knowing the name of the tags

Tags: c#, xml

I need to read an XML file without knowing the name of the tags.
Currently I am using Xelement.I need to find an efficient way to make this program.
My XML:

```
<Actions>
<Action Name="Action1" ID="AE6ECD81-6CC1-4A05-B379-113D700BD1A9">
    <Trigger Name="alo">
        <And>
            <Checked ID="3897D8C6-873F-45AD-8D28-1A80B8AC5CBD" Parameter="Attribute" Value="Checked"/>
            <Checked ID="B1BA57CD-BFAF-4C52-8686-F7073F68EF71" Parameter="Attribute" Value="unchecked"/>
        </And>
    </Trigger>
    <Command>
        <True>
            <Do ID="F9129376-DCDE-4964-8B5C-DF0EF8886AB9" Parameter="Visible" Value="True"/>
            <Do ID="456627B0-8195-459C-981F-7450866CE635" Parameter="Visible" Value="True"/>
        </True>
    </Command>
</Action>
<Action Name="Action2" ID="5E7809FF-FEAB-48F2-9F18-0E67F514AFB2">
    <Trigger>
        <Or>
            <Checked ID="3897D8C6-873F-45AD-8D28-1A80B8AC5CBD" Parameter="Attribute" Value="Checked"/>
            <Checked ID="B1BA57CD-BFAF-4C52-8686-F7073F68EF71" Parameter="Attribute" Value="unchecked"/>
        </Or>
    </Trigger>
    <Command>
        <True>
            <Do ID="F9129376-DCDE-4964-8B5C-DF0EF8886AB9" Parameter="Visible" Value="True"/>
            <Do ID="456627B0-8195-459C-981F-7450866CE635" Parameter="Visible" Value="True"/>
        </True>
    </Command>
</Action>
```

My C# code:

```
    public override void LoadFromXml(string XmlFileAddress)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(XmlFileAddress);
        var actions = doc.Descendants("Action").ToList();
        foreach (var a in actions)
        {
            xmlstring = a.ToString();
            Atcion hta = new Atcion();
            hta.LoadFromXml(xmlstring);
            ActionList.Add(hta);
         }
     }

    List<Trigger> TriggerList = new List<Trigger>();
    List<Command> CommandList = new List<Command>();
    string actname;
    string actID;
    string trigname;
    string actype;
    public override void LoadFromXml(string XmlFileAddress)
    {
        string xmlstr = "";
        XElement elem = XElement.Parse(XmlFileAddress);            
        actID = elem.Attribute("ID").Value;
        actname = elem.Attribute("Name").Value;
        var triggers = elem.Descendants("Trigger").ToList();                        
        foreach (var t in triggers)
        {
            trigname = t.Attribute("Name").Value;
            actype = t.Element("And").Name.LocalName;
            var chaction = t.Descendants("And").ToList();                
            foreach (var c in chaction)
            {
                Trigger tri = new Trigger();
                xmlstr = c.ToString();
                tri.LoadFromXml(xmlstr);
                TriggerList.Add(tri);
            }
        }
```

The only problem that I have is the fact that I need to know the name of the tags in XML.
I would be really grateful if someone tells me how I can read tags without knowing their name and offers me an efficient way to do so.

Comment: if you don't know the name of the tags, how would you figure out the *semantics* of values on that tag, so assign it to a correponding property of your object ?

Comment: Have you tried a SAX parser? It will fire events on elements and attributes found and give you the tags' names.

Comment: If you dont know the names of the tags - you can simply iterate through them all using, for example, `XElement.Elements()`. However, as mentioned by Tigran, this is meaningless since you would not know how to actually interpret those tags and their values, without _some_ prior knowladge (unless all you want to do is to add those tags to some `Dictionary<string, string>` or w/e)

Comment: @Pedram Is your real requirement to read the ID and Parameter from all tags irrespective of the tag name?

Comment: Sorry for delay,Thank you all,
@BobbyAlexander:I want to read IDs and Names of tags WITH the name of the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have the prior knowledge of `Action`, `Trigger` and `Command` and you want to parse the actions dynamically.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

var actions = xDoc.Descendants("Action")
                    .Select(action => new
                    {
                        Name = action.Attribute("Name").Value,
                        Trigger = new
                        {
                            Name = (string)action.Element("Trigger").Attribute("Name"),
                            Conditions = action.Element("Trigger")
                                            .Elements().First()
                                            .Elements()
                                            .Select(e => new{
                                                Name = e.Parent.Name.LocalName,
                                                Attributes = e.Attributes().ToDictionary(a=>a.Name.LocalName,a=>a.Value)
                                            })
                                            .ToList()

                        },
                        Command = new
                        {
                            Name = (string)action.Element("Trigger").Attribute("Name"),
                            Do = action.Element("Command")
                                       .Elements().First()
                                       .Elements()
                                       .Select(e => new
                                        {
                                            Name = e.Parent.Name.LocalName,
                                            Attributes = e.Attributes().ToDictionary(a => a.Name.LocalName, a => a.Value)
                                         })
                                        .ToList()

                        },
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you'll interpret the xml without knowing the semantics, but the following method iterates through the whole document, without knowing the elements.

```
public void ProcessXml(string XmlFileAddress)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(XmlFileAddress);

    ReadXElement(doc.Root);
}

private void ReadXElement(XElement xElement)
{
    foreach (var attribute in xElement.Attributes())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(attribute.Name + " - " + attribute.Value);
    }

    foreach (var childElement in xElement.Elements())
    {
        ReadXElement(childElement);
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]